# Cannot get route in React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I go to localhost:8080/ and refresh the expected page is hit and it constantly renders the correct page. If I click on a link it goes to the correct page but then on refresh I get the `CANNOT GET` error message

This is some of the code:

```
    <div>
      <Route strict path="/" component={Header} />
      <Route strict path="/quizzes" component={QuizList} />
    </div>
```

Just put this line into my webpack config as well:

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
```

I'm confused because it renders the correct page just on refresh it cannot get it (except for the homepage (`/`) url).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the server side. You didn't provide the code, but most likely you have the only endpoint defined at `http://localhost:8080/`. You will need a well configured server to host application using browser history such as react-router. You can take a look at this guide for example: https://medium.com/@patriciolpezjuri/using-create-react-app-with-react-router-express-js-8fa658bf892d

Comment: it says the article is out of date ?

Comment: the react-router code is outdated, but we're focusing on the server configuration